# docker proxy pull windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, proxy

After install docker v1.12.0-rc2 on windows 10 pro machine, set the http and  https variables, i get the following error:

```
docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repos
itories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate is valid for FG200B3911602237, not index.docker.io.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Answer (score 1):

world image is images for Linux container, you can't use it on windows container.
At the moment, there're only about 9 or 10 images for windows containers, you can use it follow this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/deployment.

Comment: I followed docker 'getting started " https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/, I think the error is related to a proxy configuration

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I thought you work with windows containers. Anyway, I see a thread in github of docker with same trouble https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10802

Answer (score 1):

After install  v1.12.0-rc3-beta18 build 5226 pull container works behind a proxy. tks @huy-tran